# Is it good practice to open several Kafka streams in one Spark Context?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, bigdata

We have several applications that follow the same logic and patterns, and would like to know if it's good practice to open several streams in one spark context. So the main application to submit, would have something of this sort;

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("test-app");
    conf.set("log4j.configuration", "\\log4j.properties");

    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(20));

    // Iterate streams
    for (RealtimeApplication app : realtimeApplications)
    { 
        app.execute(ssc); 
    }

    // Trigger!
    ssc.start();

    // Await stopping of the service...
    ssc.awaitTermination();
```

Then, in the implementation of the abstract method `execute(JavaStreamingContext ssc)` you would have the following code...

```
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, this.getZkQuorum(), this.getSparkGroup(), topicsSet);

        JavaDStream<String> lines = kafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {

            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {

                // Extract transation
                String value = tuple2._2();

                // Do something here...
                String result = executeSomething(value);

                return result;
            }
        });
```

Is this something to be considered wrong in Spark development?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather share your logic through RDD like

```
JavaDStream<String> lines1 = kafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {...});
JavaDStream<String> lines2 = kafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {...});
JavaDStream<String> lines3 = kafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {...});
```

With one source stream

Comment: Logic is also shared through the RDD. The purpose for this is to configure applications, and set them during runtime. So you would open a spark context, and then according to the configurations include logic for the transactions received from the stream. So you can have a configuration that specifies to stream from a Kafka topic, and if the value of property X is 1, write the value to Hbase.

Comment: I am not really good at Spark Java API, but in scala we always use `scalaz` to compose logic, for example imagine you have stream val stream d =... and you need to process it in accordance of config file with 3 different logics => we do the following (logic1 &&& logic2 &&& logic3 ).apply(stream). this will return to us the tuple (result1, result2, result3)

Comment: @Mez I bet you can compose your logic with Google Guava http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Functions.html

Comment: Hi @ponkin - the generalisation that we are after goes beyond the utility functions that we can use in the RDD. That is already being done. The idea is to have configured several applications that go through the same process, and use one code base. So launch several streams, each stream with specific rules, yet all of these launched within 1 application with little effort.